# Не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "const std::string" в "double"

Tags: c++, строки, типы-данных, преобразование-типов

Всем привет,столкнулся с такой проблемой "Не существует подходящей функции преобразования из "const std::string" в "double"" в строчке 52.Как ее решить?И извините за плохо вставленный код,еще не научился правильно вставлять коды в этом сайте.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class Contingent {
protected:
string firstname, lastname;
int age;
public:
Contingent(string = "John", string = "Jones", int = 32);
~Contingent() = default;
void printClass()const;
};
class HeightSchool {
protected:
string name;
int departments;
public:
HeightSchool(string = "Brighton", int = 5);
~HeightSchool() = default;
void printClass()const;
double getPub()const;
};
class Bachelor :public Contingent, public HeightSchool {
string specialty;
int grade;
public:
Bachelor(string = "Chemist", int = 51);
~Bachelor() = default;
bool operator <(const Bachelor&);
friend istream& operator >>(istream&, Bachelor&);
friend ostream& operator <<(ostream&, const Bachelor&);
};
Contingent::Contingent(string f, string l, int a) :
firstname(f), lastname(l), age(a) {}

void Contingent::printClass()const {
cout << "Saxeli: " << firstname
    << "\nGvari: " << lastname
    << "\nAsaki: " << age << endl;
    }

    HeightSchool::HeightSchool(string n, int d) :
    name(n), departments(d) {}

   void HeightSchool::printClass()const {
    cout << "Dasaxeleba: " << name
    << "\nFakultetebis ricxvi: " << departments << endl;
    }
    double HeightSchool::getPub()const { return name; }

    Bachelor::Bachelor(string s, int g) :
    Contingent(), HeightSchool(), specialty(s), grade(g) {}

    bool Bachelor::operator <(const Bachelor& l) {
    return this->grade < l.grade;
    }

    istream& operator >>(istream& in, Bachelor& l) {
    return in >> l.firstname >> l.lastname
    >> l.age >> l.name >> l.departments
    >> l.specialty >> l.grade;
    }
    ostream& operator <<(ostream& out, const Bachelor& l) {
     return out << "Saxeli: " << l.firstname
    << "\nGvari: " << l.lastname
    << "\nAsaki: " << l.age
    << "\nDasaxeleba: " << l.name
    << "\nFakultetebis ricxvi: " << l.departments
    << "\nSpecialoba: " << l.specialty
    << "\nShefaseba: " << l.grade << endl;
       }

        void fillArray(Bachelor*, int&);
    void printArray(const Bachelor*, int&);
    void intoFile(const Bachelor*, int&);

    int main() {
     static Contingent C("Dustin", "Poirier", 32);
     C.printClass();
       cout << "--------------------" << endl;

        static HeightSchool H("Tonbridge", 4);
         H.printClass();
      cout << "--------------------" << endl;

        Bachelor* ptr = new(nothrow) Bachelor[1200];
         int realSize{ 0 };
      fillArray(ptr, realSize);
     sort(ptr, ptr + realSize, [](Bachelor& k, Bachelor& l) { return l < k; });
     printArray(ptr, realSize);

     intoFile(ptr, realSize);

      delete[] ptr;
      ptr = nullptr;
      }

      void fillArray(Bachelor* arr, int& n) {
        ifstream ifs("bachelor.txt");
        while (!ifs.eof()) {
            ifs >> arr[n++];
        }
        ifs.close();
        }

       void printArray(const Bachelor* arr, int& n) {
       for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cout << arr[i];
    cout << "--------------------" << endl;
      }
     }

    void intoFile(const Bachelor* arr, int& n) {
ofstream ofs("report.txt");
ofs << "Yvelaze udidesi shefaseba:\n\n";
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    ofs << arr[i];
    if ((arr + i)->getPub() != (arr + i + 1)->getPub()) {
        break;
    }
}
ofs << "--------------------" << endl;

ofs << "Yvelaze umciresi shefaseba:\n\n";
for (int i = n - 1; i >= 0; ++i) {
    ofs << arr[i];
    if ((arr + n - i)->getPub() != (arr + n - i - 1)->getPub()) {
        break;
    }
}
ofs << "--------------------" << endl;

int average = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    average += (arr + i)->getPub();
}
average /= n;

int index = 0, dif = abs((arr)->getPub() - average);
for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
    if (abs((arr + i)->getPub() - average) < dif) {
        index = i;
        dif = abs((arr + i)->getPub() - average);
    }
}
ofs << "Yvelaze axlos yvela bakalavris sashualo shefasebastan:\n\n";
ofs << arr[index];
ofs << "--------------------" << endl;
ofs.close();
}
```

Comment: Если проблема в одной строчке, то зачем вы прикладываете весь проект?

Comment: А слабО ее выделить, например, комментарием?

Comment: `double d; sscanf(name.c_str(),"%lf",&d);return d;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double HeightSchool::getPub()const { return name; }
```

Что такое `name`? Строка. Вы возвращаете строку, но требуете, чтобы было возвращено значение типа `double`. Вам ничего не кажется странным?

Можно, конечно, так:

```
double HeightSchool::getPub()const { return stod(name); }
```

Это скомпилируется... Но есть ли хоть какая-то *гарантия*, что в `name` будет именно строковое представление числа `double`? Может, ст*о*ит пересмотреть свой проект?

Да, еще потом у вас

```
int average = 0;
...
average += (arr + i)->getPub();
```

т.е. вы еще и это преобразованное в `double` значение дополнительно преобразуете в `int`. Ой, неладно что-то в датском королевстве...

Comment: Как обычно, анонимный минус без пояснений? Похоже, кому-то не хватает IQ, чтобы понимать ответы, но еще проще излагать их я не могу...

Answer (score -1):

Я не буду даже пытаться разобраться в вашем коде, но за правильное переобразование типа данных отвечает static_cast

```
//...
int n = 45;
double d = static_cast<double>(n);
std::cout << a << ", " << d;
//...
```

В консоли выведется: *45, 45.0*

Но для прямого преобразования string в double static_cast не сработает

Поэтому вы можете воспользоваться моим кодом, который я писал для себя ради интереса

```
// проверяет строку на то, что ее содержимое сможет
// сконвертироваться в double
bool doubleSigned(const std::string& s)
{
    size_t offset=0;
    if(s[offset]=='-')
        ++offset;
    return s.find_first_not_of("0123456789.,", offset) == std::string::npos;
}

double in_double(std::string &str)
{
// если можно сконвертировать
if (doubleSigned(str))
{
    int factor, sign, symbol, value = 0;
    
    // вычисляем знак числа (+/-)
    if (static_cast<int>(str.at(0)) == 45)
    {
        factor = -1;
        sign = 0;
    }
    else 
    {
        factor = 1;
        sign = -1;
    }
        
    int counter = 0;
    int point = 0;
    
    // конвертируем
    for (int i = str.size() - 1; i > sign; i--)
    {
        // берем номер символа 
        symbol = static_cast<int>(str.at(i));

        // если символ = "." или "," то устанавливаем ее
        // позицию
        if (symbol == 44 || symbol == 46)
        {
                
            if (point == 0)
            {
                int power = 0;
                point = 1;
                while (power < counter)
                {
                    point *= 10;
                    power++;
                }
            
                counter++;
            }
            
            continue;
        }
        
        // записываем символ в число
        value += (static_cast<int>(str.at(i)) - 48) * factor;
        factor *= 10;
        counter++;
    }
    
    // конвертируем полученное чисоло в double
    // вставляем точку на ее законное место
    double d = static_cast<double>(value) / static_cast<double>(point);
    return d;
}
// в качестве возвращаемого значения предлагаю 
// возвращать указатель, а не так как тут, чтоб
// в случае неудачной конвертации возвращался
// nullptr
else
    return -1.0;
}
```

Я не знаю, как оценят код специалисты, но он работает. Я соглашусь, если в нем много всего лишнего, но не судите строго, я тоже новичок.

Comment: Зачем преобразовывать руками, если есть `std::to_string`?

Comment: Потому что я ещё не разбираюсь со всеми методами std::string. Надо читать документацию, изучать. А мне было просто интересно, когда я писал преобразование руками

Comment: Воу, погоди. to_string конвертирует double в string. А надо string в double. Разве не так?

Comment: Начиная с с++11 есть std::stod. Надо разобраться в нем

Comment: Конвертните `2.3e-5`, например :)